# Android Twilio Token expiration While the app is in background

Tags: android, twilio

When the app is closed and the app is in background so how can i check the token is expired or not because i have to fetch the token in background when it will expire.

I will try this : [Application is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background)

but i can't find the exact solution to the problem.

Comment: when the token expires, the stopListening() method of device listener is called. So you can generate the new token as stopListening() is called

Comment: @BhoomiZalavadiya where can one find this `stopListening()` function?